Creating an array with a variable length (1 dimensional) vba
I have tried to teach myself about arrays by reading other posts and watching videos. And where application meets knowledge, I am failing. For now, I believe I need to use a 1 dimensional array to write to a single row multi-column array. Maybe a 2D array may be easier. I only hesitate on the 2D because I am so new to arrays, perhaps baby steps.
I am forecasting a dynamic number of accounts over for a dynamic number of years. Currently the code uses the basic read, calc, write to cell, then loop to next as a structure. Each account is written to a row on the data sheet with each year as a column. I have a starting amount. I then do calculations on that amount to create Year1 amount. Then Year2 amount is using the same set of calculations but would have a basis of Year1 amount.  (The calculations are too complex to explain for this post.) The calculated values would be stored in the array and written to a data sheet once the x number of years is reached, which is where I get a 1D array idea. Each account is a loop in the code with each year being a loop with in the account loop. Or If I wait until all accounts are processed in an array, I suppose that is where a 2D array may be handy. (That loop also contains the creation and calculations 2 other data sets. I only bring those up as Imay eventually use arrays to manage them once I master the first one.) The code is hundreds of lines long, and has other procedure calls, so too long to post.
But for now, I am finding I cannot set up a 1D array with a variable, as debug tells me it must be a constant. This is just a test code, that once I get to work would be applied within the large procedure.
Sub TestArrays()
    Dim iYrCount As Variant, rg As Range, iRowCtr As Integer, iLastSourceRow As Integer, snFactor As Single

    iYrCount = 30 'Hardcoded for this post. It is dynamically set earlier in the sub
    iLastSourceRow = 20 'Source of account names and metadata. Again, it is hardcoded for this post.
    
    iRowCtr = 1
    Dim arr(iYrCount) As Variant, icol As Variant
    Do Until iRowCtr = iLastSourceRow + 1
        icol = 1
        For Each icol In arr
            'Do stuff...
            arr(icol) = arr(icol - 1) * snFactor 'although much more complex than this.
        '    icol = icol + 1
        Next
        Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & iRowCtr)
        rg = arr
    Loop
    iRowCtr = iRowCtr + 1
    
End Sub

Thanks for any help or advice.

https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/#Two_Types_of_VBA_Arrays

Instead asking about array, please try explaining what you try accomplishing using an array. We will be able to help only if we understand what you try doing. I must confess that looking to your code I cannot understand... Then, basically you need to load the array. Secondly, how you need/intend to use the processed array? Based on these aspect we can recommend what type of array to use and maybe a piece of code able to solve the issue...


Using Dim arr(iYrCount) As Variant you only declare the variable. You set that it must have iYrCount + 1 elements (+ 1 because the 1D arrays are 0 based, except the case of using Option Base 1). In order to process its elements you must load it.

You can use a 2D array type declaring Dim myArr, then load it myArr = Range("A2:F2").value. You will load a 2D array (one row and 6 columns).
Or a 1D array myArr = Array(2, 5, 10, 15, 4) containing 5 elements (Ubound(myArr) will return 4)

You can drop the array content in a range in the next way (for 2D type):

 Range("A3").Resize(ubound(myArr), Ubound(myArr, 2)).value = myAr

For 1D type:
 Range("A3").Resize(1, Ubound(myArr) + 1).value = myAr` '+ 1 because of its zero base type


I think you have given me the tips I need. I unfrotnately need to head out now, and may not be able to get back to this until tomorrow. Thanks again.
